# Is there a way to do a serverless JSON capture through jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm working on a serverless web app - JS + jQuery, CSS, HTML in a flat file - and I want to make a GET request to pickup some JSON data.

The only method I've seen is through AJAX-y methods which require the use of a backend server to handle sending the REST request... but I don't have a backend server.

How can I do this, all from within on JS script/file?

Comment: You want to do a GET request but not use a server? I don't understand.

Comment: The solution is simply: I can't.

Same origin policy prevents this, explicitly.

Comment: You want to do a GET... from where?  You tell us the source you want to GET from, and we'll show you how to do it.

Comment: Can you give us some insight on what do you want to achieve? A "serverless web app" is a bit of a paradox in itself. If you don't have a server, where is the data coming from, how are you planning to give people access to your "web app"? If it's just a static local page with a few scripts, can you not store your static data locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a great mocking library for jquery that does what paykroyd suggests.

https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax

http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/mock-your-ajax-requests-with-mockjax-for-rapid-development/

It will intercept urls matching a regex and let you respond with whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to replace the JQuery ajax function with our own that will return data however you want without going to a server. Something like:

```
    $.ajax = function(queryParams) {

        // parse the params and create a return data object

        var data = {x: 1};

        queryParams.success(data);

    };
```